# New port on routers IP

Tags: networking, router

I have a router at 17.17.17.150 and a pc hosting a website at 17.17.17.2:80

I want to open a new port at my router So, that when I enter 17.17.17.150:9001 I get the 17.17.17.2:80 website of the PC

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's not a valid RFC1918 IP [local LAN IP subnets], unless that's your WAN IP, and if so, that should never be shared online.  As to the question, you'd configure a port redirect on the router.

Comment: As said, you need a port forwarding. Search for your router  on [this site](https://portforward.com/) for instructions.